# Probability of failing to decode a biased die

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, dice

Say we are given a biased die that shows up two of its sides (maybe $1$ and $2$) with a probability of $0.8$ and the rest of the sides (maybe $3,4,5,$ and $6$) with a probability of $0.2$.In order to determine the favoured sides, we will repeatedly throw the dice and create a frequency histogram.

In an ideal case, say we throw the dice a 1000 times, then we will expect the favoured sides to show up a significantly larger number of times than others. Specifically, in this particular example, sides $1$ and $2$ are expected to show up around $400$ times while the remaining sides are expected to show up around $50$ times each, and we can easily make a judgment.

We are tasked with determining the probability of making a false judgment - that is the possibility that we determine that sides, such as 1 and 3 are the favoured sides, instead of the true favoured sides 1 and 2 after we roll the die R number of times in total?

-- Adding some clarifications based on comments

We only know the count of favoured sides and not their identity. It may happen that sides $3$ and $4$ appear $450$ and $350$ times, respectively; even though 1 and 2 are favoured, they may appear only $45$ and $55$ times, respectively.

I was hoping to figure out the probability of this unlikely event and show that though it is positive, it will be insignificant when R is high. Further, maybe come up with some lower bounds on R.

Comment: The natural decision is choose the two faces appearing most often.  But there is always a positive probability that you could get ties for second place, and this is substantial enough to worry about when $R$ is small.  What would you do then?

Comment: @Henry Your comment analogizes to NBA playoff sports betting.  The weaker team has a better chance of upsetting the stronger team in a best-of-5-game series than a best-of-7-game-series.  Here, I am ignoring shifting win factors as a result of home field or psychology, and assuming that the stronger team has a (constant) fixed probability of winning each individual game.

Comment: Thank You for the comments. 
@Henry: Yes, I am trying to calculate the probability of this unlucky event when there is a tie in the second position or, worse when none of the favoured sides show up more often. For instance, sides 3 and 4 appear around 400 times each even though 1 and 2 are favoured.

Comment: The key issue is that we do not know which are the favoured sides. We only know the number of favoured sides.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, with respect to the NBA playoff, the assumption is valid that stronger and weaker teams have a fixed probability of winning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum-2 just added, at the end of this answer, to respond to the OP's (i.e. original poster's) comment/question.

---

See the just added Addendum, which adjusts my response based on the OP's (i.e. original poster's) editing of the original question.

I (somewhat) buried the response in the Addendum, rather than revising the entire answer, because the original work will be very valuable, in fine tuning the computations.

That is, it becomes easier to piggy back the final computations off of the original work.

---

If the following simplifying assumptions are off point, please advise.  Then, I will probably have to delete this answer.  If I understand correctly, this is a conditional Probability problem, rather than a Statistics problem.

Assume that you have thrown the die $1000$ times and it has come up:

- $1$: 400 times.
- $2$: 400 times.
- $3$ through $6$ : 50 times each.

Further assume that you know that the die is biased and that two of the sides will appear $40\%$ each, while the other $4$ sides will appear $5\%$ each.

Further assume that you know that one of the biased sides is the side where $1$ shows face up on the die.

Further assume that you kinow that the other biased side is either $2$ face up or $3$ face up, on the die.

---

So, you attach the probability of the data of $1000$ rolls occuring, given each of the $2$ hypotheses.  Then, you have the relative probability of each of the hypotheses being true.

$\underline{\text{Case 1: the biased sides are 1 and 2}}$
Then, the probability of the experimental data occurring is

$$P_1 = \left[\binom{1000}{400} \times (.4)^{400}\right]
\times \left[\binom{600}{400} \times (.4)^{400}\right]$$

$$ \times \left[\binom{200}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right]
\times \left[\binom{150}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right]$$

$$ \times \left[\binom{100}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right]
\times \left[\binom{50}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right].$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2: the biased sides are 1 and 3}}$
Then, the probability of the experimental data occurring is

$$P_2 = \left[\binom{1000}{400} \times (.4)^{400}\right]
\times \left[\binom{600}{400} \times (.05)^{400}\right]$$

$$ \times \left[\binom{200}{50} \times (.4)^{50}\right]
\times \left[\binom{150}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right]$$

$$ \times \left[\binom{100}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right]
\times \left[\binom{50}{50} \times (.05)^{50}\right].$$

---

Then, the probability that Case 1 is accurate, rather than Case 2 is

$$\frac{P_1}{P_1 + P_2}
= \frac{(.4)^{400} \times (.05)^{50}}{\left[(.4)^{400} \times (.05)^{50}\right] ~~+~~ \left[(.05)^{400} \times (.4)^{50}\right]}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Altering the problem.

Suppose that the original problem that is analyzed above is altered, in the following way:

You know that exactly $2$ of the $6$ sides are biased, but you don't know which of the $2$ sides are the ones that are biased.  All that you have is the experimental data described at the start of this problem, where the numbers $(1)$ and $(2)$ each occurred $400$ times, while each of the other numbers occurred $50$ times each.

---

So, instead of two competing hypotheses, that the biased sides are either [1::3] or [1::2], you have $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} = 15~$ competing hypotheses, because that is how many combinations there are of $6$ items, selected $2$ at a time, without replacement.

So, refer to these hypotheses (i.e. events) as 
$E_1, E_2, \cdots, E_{14}, E_{15}.$

Let $P_k$ denote the probability that the experimental data occurred, under the assumption that hypothesis $E_k$ is accurate, for $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,15\}.$

Let $W = P_1 + P_2 + \cdots + P_{14} + P_{15}.$

Then, the probability that hypothesis $E_k$ is accurate is

$$\frac{P_k}{W} \tag1 .$$

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to computing each of $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{15}.$

---

Note that it is not necessary to compute each of $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{15}$ exactly.  Instead, given the computation in (1) above, all that is necessary is to compute the **relative magnitudes** of $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{15}$.

---

To formalize the computations, I will label the events (i.e. hypotheses) as follows:

$E_1~:~$ [1::2] are the biased sides. 
$E_2~:~$ [1::3] are the biased sides. 
$E_3~:~$ [1::4] are the biased sides. 
$E_4~:~$ [1::5] are the biased sides. 
$E_5~:~$ [1::6] are the biased sides.

$E_6~:~$ [2::3] are the biased sides. 
$E_7~:~$ [2::4] are the biased sides. 
$E_8~:~$ [2::5] are the biased sides. 
$E_9~:~$ [2::6] are the biased sides.

$E_{10}~:~$ [3::4] are the biased sides. 
$E_{11}~:~$ [3::5] are the biased sides. 
$E_{12}~:~$ [3::6] are the biased sides.

$E_{13}~:~$ [4::5] are the biased sides. 
$E_{14}~:~$ [4::6] are the biased sides.

$E_{15}~:~$ [5::6] are the biased sides.

---

Then, computing the relative magnitudes:

$\displaystyle P_1 ~:$

$\displaystyle \left[(.4)^{400}\right]^2 \times \left[(.05)^{50}\right]^4.$

Each of $P_2$ through $P_9 ~:$

$\left[(.4)^{400}\right] 
\times \left[(.05)^{400}\right]
\times \left[(.4)^{50}\right]
\times \left[(.05)^{50}\right]^3.$

Each of $P_{10}$ through $P_{15} ~:$

$\left[(.05)^{400}\right]^2 
\times \left[(.4)^{50}\right]^2
\times \left[(.05)^{50}\right]^2.$

---

**Addendum-2**
Responding to the comment/question of the OP (i.e. original poster)

> This solution works for a fixed output probability distribution. But not sure how to generalise it. For instance the output probability distribution could be like {1:450, 2:350, 3:45, 4:55, 5:50, 6:50} or it could be like {1:710, 2:80, 3:30, 4:60, 5:60, 6:60}

I will piggyback off of the Addendum, which itself piggybacks off of the initial answer.

For illustration, I will attack each of the $2$ hypothetical observed distributions separately.

In both cases, I will start with the presumptions  that:

- The die has $2$ biased sides.
- Each of the $2$ biased sides has a probability of $(0.4)$ of appearing.
- Each of the other $4$ sides has a probability of $(0.05)$ of appearing.
- As in the first Addendum, it is unknown, which of the $2$ sides are the biased sides.
- As in the first Addendum, you have $(15)$ competing hypotheses.
- As in the first Addendum, you will need to be able to compute the relative magnitude of the probabilities of each of these $(15)$ hypotheses.
- Once this is done, the computations should parallel that in the first Addendum, where you first calculate $W$ and then calculate $~\displaystyle \frac{P_k}{W}.$
- Therefore, all that is necessary is to illustrate, with each of the $(2)$ hypothetical distributions, the algorithm to follow to compute the relative magnitudes of $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{15}.$

---

Assume that you have a distribution of 
$\{1:a_1\}$ 
$\{2:a_2\}$ 
$\{3:a_3\}$ 
$\{4:a_4\}$ 
$\{5:a_5\}$ 
$\{6:a_6\}.$

This means that it is being assumed that you rolled the die $(a_1 + \cdots + a_6)$ times, and the number $k$ appeared $(a_k)$ times.

You have $15$ relative probabilities to compute: 
$P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{15}.$

Assume that $r \in \{1,2,\cdots,15\}$. 
Assume that you are computing the relative 
magnitude of $P_r$ which represents the probability 
that hypothesis $E_r$ is accurate.

Assume that with respect to hypothesis $E_r:$
The probability of the die rolling a $k$ is 
presumed to be $s_k$ 
where $s_1 + s_2 + \cdots s_6 = 1.$

Then, the relative magnitude of $P_r$ should be computed as

$$\text{Relative magnitude of} ~P_r = \prod_{i=1}^6 (s_i)^{a_i}. \tag2 $$

For illustration purposes, I will select an arbitrary $P_r$ to compute for Distribution-1, and an arbitrary $P_r$ to compute for Distribution-2.

$\underline{\text{Distribution-1} ~: ~\{1:450, 2:350, 3:45, 4:55, 5:50, 6:50\}}$ 
Here, you have that 
$(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_6) = (450,350,45,55,50,50).$

Suppose that I am computing the relative magnitude of $P_8$, for Distribution-1.

The assigned probabilities for $(s_1,\cdots,s_6)$ 
that represent hypothesis $E_8$ are 
$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5,s_6) = (0.05, 0.4, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4, 0.05).$

Therefore, for Distribution-1, the relative magnitude of $P_8$ is computed as

$$\left[(0.05)^{450}\right] \times 
\left[(0.4)^{350}\right] \times 
\left[(0.05)^{45}\right] \times 
\left[(0.05)^{55}\right] \times 
\left[(0.4)^{50}\right] \times 
\left[(0.05)^{50}\right].$$

$\underline{\text{Distribution-2} ~: ~\{1:710, 2:80, 3:30, 4:60, 5:60, 6:60\}}$ 
Here, you have that 
$(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_6) = (710,80,30,60,60,60).$

Suppose that I am computing the relative magnitude of $P_{12}$, for Distribution-2.

The assigned probabilities for $(s_1,\cdots,s_6)$ 
that represent hypothesis $E_{12}$ are 
$(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5,s_6) = (0.05, 0.05, 0.4, 0.05, 0.05, 0.4).$

Therefore, for Distribution-2, the relative magnitude of $P_{12}$ is computed as

$$\left[(0.05)^{710}\right] \times 
\left[(0.05)^{80}\right] \times 
\left[(0.4)^{30}\right] \times 
\left[(0.05)^{60}\right] \times 
\left[(0.05)^{60}\right] \times 
\left[(0.4)^{60}\right].$$

Comment: Thank you for sparing time and working out the probability, but the assumptions are inaccurate.

Comment: Specifically, if any two sides show up a significantly higher number of times, then it will be natural to select them as the favoured sides. But the issue is that we only know the count of favoured sides and not their identity. It may happen that sides 3 and 4 appear 450 and 350 times, respectively; even though 1 and 2 are favoured, they may appear only 45 and 55 times, respectively.

Comment: "We are tasked with determining the probability of making a false judgment - that is the possibility that we determine that sides, such as 1 and 3 are the favoured sides, instead of the true favoured sides 1 and 2 after we roll the die " : I can only interpret this in one way : you have $2$ hypotheses: [1] the biased sides are 1 and 3 **or** [2] the biased sides are 1 and 2.  Did I misinterpret your intent, re the portion of your posting that I have excerpted at the start of my comment?

Comment: I was hoping to figure out the probability of this unlikely event and show that though it is positive, it will be insignificant when R is high. Further, maybe come up with some lower bounds on R.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I will update the post. What I was trying to convey is that, we only know the count of favoured sides and not their identity. It may happen that sides 3 and 4 appear 450 and 350 times, respectively; even though 1 and 2 are favoured, they may appear only 45 and 55 times, respectively.

Comment: @jaswantmeena See my just posted comment, following this answer.  Based on your comments, the situation seems to revert to the **Shooting Gallery Blues**.  In other words, based on your original posting, you are asking me to hit a **moving target**.  Please edit your question directly, to nail down the exact Mathematical problem that you want attacked.  **Then**, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @jaswantmeena First see the just added new section, at the very start of my answer.  Then, I suggest that you review the original answer.  Then, see the Addendum, which I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135627/discussion-between-jaswant-meena-and-user2661923).

Comment: Thank You for the answer with a very detailed explanation. This solution works for a fixed output probability distribution. But not sure how to generalise it. For instance the output probability distribution could be like {1:450, 2:350, 3:45, 4:55, 5:50, 6:50} or it could be like {1:710, 2:80, 3:30, 4:60, 5:60, 6:60}

Comment: @jaswantmeena First see the just added new section, at the very start of my answer. Then, see Addendum-2, at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank You for the clear explanation. The answer seems perfect.

Comment: Now, if somehow we know that $E_1$ is the correct hypothesis, then basically, the probability of failure will be $\sum_{r = 2}^{15} P_r$

Comment: If you know that $E_1$ is correct, then the probability of failure will be $$\frac{W - P_1}{W}.$$

Comment: @jaswantmeena This problem that you have referred to is a complicated an exhausting problem that is really beyond my knowledge.  The answer that I gave, which avoided statistics, and stuck with bernoulli trials, is really at the edge of my knowledge.  Perhaps somebody else will step up.

Comment: Thank You for helping with this problem with clear explanations. It really helped to improve my understanding.